# Is it possible to force eager loading on "New" objects in sqlalchemy

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, eager-loading

I am trying to improve the throughput of a create function on a server with reasonably high latency to the sql server, and noticed that sqlalchemy appears to lazy load even if the relationships are set to `lazy='joined'`

The code is simple

```
Event.New(**event_data)
return Event.to_dict()
```

The Event.to_dict() method just outputs all of the fields including the relationships as a dictionary.

If I set `sqlalchemy.engine` to `DEBUG` I can see that the `to_dict` method is causing the creation of a select statement for the main object as well as one for each of the relationships.

I have set all of the relationships in the model to `lazy='joined'` but this has not changed the number of SQL statements generated.

Is there a way of forcing the population of a New() object to be eager loaded?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem? Thanks.

Comment: I could not find a way within SQLAlchemy so I "manually" just output the input data rather than fetched from the DB.